# AngularJS, Grunt server and socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, gruntjs, yeoman

After 3 hours of combining I decide to write question here.

I'm trying write a application on my pc using `yeoman` for building application. I'm trying use `socket.io` but I see 404.

### What I do

1. I have installed yeoman.
2. I have installed socket.io under `/node_modules/`
3. I have installed `angular-socket-io` by bower
4. In my index.html I have included needed scripts: [index.html](https://github.com/w00caSh/FunWithAngular/blob/master/app/index.html)
5. In app.js I added module `btford.socket-io`
6. In my controller I inject socket : `.controller('ChatCtrl', function ($scope, socket) {`
7. And I run? server using `grunt server` command

So where I make mistake or what I wrong understand so my application can't find socket.io.js file?

Here you can find my full code: https://github.com/w00caSh/FunWithAngular

### EDIT:

It's very important. Do I have to enable any node server for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, that I used wrong code for listening sockets in `server.js` file.

I rewrite this **[file](https://github.com/lzak/FunWithAngular/commit/40df2b85985b0136e9d60c5b6e49d2793430be59)** and now it's working well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution on GitHub. Works great with my famo.us project! I'm trying to figure out for days to connect to a MySQL database using socket.io and a Yeoman app, but this is the solution I was looking for.